# php echo function not printing result

Tags: php, function

I have a script to count the time a ticket is open each day, but only for hours we are open.  The details of the functions arent that important but i have pasted it all here as it may be the cause for the failure.

Heres the function:

```
function getTime($o, $now, $total) {

    //One Day in seconds
    $oneDay = 86400;

    //One Business day (12 hours, 7am-7pm)
    $oneBDay = 43200;

    //Get the timestamp of 7am/7pm for time given

    $sevenAM = mktime('7', '0', '0', m($o), d($o), y($o));
    $sevenPM = mktime('19', '0', '0', m($o), d($o), y($o));

    //If Ticket Start Time is before 7am, we only count from 7am after
    if ($o < $sevenAM) {
        $o = $sevenAM;
    } else {
        $o = $o;
    }

    //Debug to get today
    $today = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', $o);

    //See if we are within the same business day
    $diff = $now - $o;

    //Debug
    //echo $today.",".$timeSpent.",".$total."\n";

    //If we are not within 1 business day, do this again
    if ($diff > $oneBDay) {

        //Total Time spent for the day
        $timeSpent = $sevenPM - $o;

        //Add todays time to total time
        $total = $total + $timeSpent;

        //Move to tomorrow
        $o = $sevenAM + $oneDay;

        getTime($o, $now, $total);
    }

    //If we are within 1 business day, count the time for today and return our result
    if ($diff < $oneBDay) {
        $time = $diff;
        $total = $total + $time; //for example $total = 123456
                    return $total;
            }
}
```

when I do

```
echo getTime($o,$now,0);
```

I would expect to see 123456. But i get nothing printed.

The function runs and I know total has a value ( I have set it statically as a debug).

--Note the function calls itself if needed

additional functions:

```
function y($o){

    $y = date('Y',$o);
    return $y;
}
function m($o){
    $m = date('m',$o);
    return $m;
}
function d($o){
    $d = date('d',$o);
    return $d;
}
```

EDIT:

if i do :

```
        if ($diff < $oneBDay) {
        $time = $diff;
        $total = $total + $time; //for example $total = 123456
        echo "My Total:".$total;
                    return $total;
            }
```

I will see My Total:123456

Comment: When you call `getTime($o,$now,0);` what are the actual values for `$o` and `$now` ?

Comment: $o is a unix timestamp of when the ticket was opened.  $now is unix time for this moment date('U').

Comment: $total = $total+$time`;` //for example $total = 123456; missing semicolon

Comment: sometimes, your function does not return any value.

Comment: That's ok, but what are the actual values you run for testing so I can perform an analog test on my side?

Comment: $o = 1534964212. 
$now = date('U');

Comment: Thanks, can you also provide the definition onf `m()` ?

Comment: added to original question

Comment: Your getTime function only return values if `$diff < $oneBDay`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not in vain to point out that your function is hard to debug due to structural flaws. I suggest you to create a Unit Test for your function and then refactor so you will be able to make sure that you preserve the desired behaviour.

That said, your function is printing anything because it's not reaching any explicit `return` directive. So it returns `null`. See that if the last if is not hit, you will miss the last chance for returning a value.

I'm not sure what your function should do, but it looks like if you call it recursively, you may want to return it's value, or at least reassign to a variable. Checkout for that.

```
<?php

function y($o){ $y = date('Y',$o); return $y; }
function m($o){ $m = date('m',$o); return $m; }
function d($o){ $d = date('d',$o); return $d; }


function getTime($o,$now,$total){

//One Day in seconds
$oneDay = 86400;

//One Business day (12 hours, 7am-7pm)
$oneBDay = 43200;

//Get the timestamp of 7am/7pm for time given

    $sevenAM = mktime('7','0','0',m($o),d($o),y($o));
    $sevenPM = mktime('19','0','0',m($o),d($o),y($o));

//If Ticket Start Time is before 7am, we only count from 7am after
    if ($o < $sevenAM){
            $o = $sevenAM;
    }else{
            $o = $o;
    }

//Debug to get today
    $today = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a',$o);

//See if we are within the same business day
    $diff = $now - $o;

//Debug
    //echo $today.",".$timeSpent.",".$total."\n";

//If we are not within 1 business day, do this again
            if ($diff > $oneBDay){

                    //Total Time spent for the day
                    $timeSpent = $sevenPM - $o;

                    //Add todays time to total time
                    $total = $total+$timeSpent;

                    //Move to tomorrow
                    $o = $sevenAM+$oneDay;

                    return getTime($o,$now,$total); // LOOKS LIKE YOU WANT TO RETURN VALUE HERE
            }

//If we are within 1 business day, count the time for today and return our result
            if($diff < $oneBDay){
                    $time = $diff;
                    $total = $total+$time; // FIXED MISSING SEMICOLON HERE TO AVOID SYNTAX ERROR
                    return $total;
            }
 }


$test = getTime(1534964212, date('U'), 0);

echo "$test"; // 144885

?>
```

Comment: Glad to know. Welcome.

Comment: Still will not output anything if `$o == $now`

Comment: im aware.  still working out a few kinks.  This will be a nightly report so its highly unlikely that a ticket will be created the exact seconds this report runs, but I appreciated your input.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not exactly sure what you tried to do with this function, I've corrected a few syntax errors, and added some returns for cases that were missing. (inside `if ($diff > $oneBDay) {` and changed `if ($diff < $oneBDay) {` to `if ($diff <= $oneBDay) {`)

```
<?php

    function getTime($o, $now, $total) {

        //One Day in seconds
        $oneDay = 86400;

        //One Business day (12 hours, 7am-7pm)
        $oneBDay = 43200;

        //Get the timestamp of 7am/7pm for time given

        $sevenAM = mktime('7', '0', '0', m($o), d($o), y($o));
        $sevenPM = mktime('19', '0', '0', m($o), d($o), y($o));

        //If Ticket Start Time is before 7am, we only count from 7am after
        if ($o < $sevenAM) {
            $o = $sevenAM;
        }

        //See if we are within the same business day
        $diff = $now - $o;

        //If we are not within 1 business day, do this again
        if ($diff > $oneBDay) {

            //Total Time spent for the day
            $timeSpent = $sevenPM - $o;

            //Add todays time to total time
            $total = $total + $timeSpent;

            //Move to tomorrow
            $o = $sevenAM + $oneDay;

            return getTime($o, $now, $total);
        }

        //If we are within 1 business day, count the time for today and return our result
        if ($diff <= $oneBDay) {
            $time = $diff;
            $total = $total + $time; //for example $total = 123456;
            return $total;
        }
    }

    function y($o){ $y = date('Y',$o); return $y; }

    function m($o){ $y = date('m',$o); return $y; }

    function d($o){ $y = date('d',$o); return $y; }

    $o = 1534964212;
    $now = date('U');

    echo getTime($o,$now,0);
```

now it returns something like `145111`